# Hide part of UIView under above transparent View

Tags: ios, objective-c, mask, uipangesturerecognizer

I am moving a `UITableView` from the bottom of the screen to the middle with a `panGesture`. My view consists of:

1. ***First layer:*** A UIImageView (fills screen)
2. ***Second Layer:*** The Table View
3. ***Third Layer*** Bottom View

Both the `TableView` and `BottomView` are translucent, to see the image. The `BottomView` is on the bottom of the screen `([[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.height - 50)`, and a height of 50. Initially the `TableView.frame.origin.y` is equal to the screen height. With the pan gesture, the user swipes up to bring the `TableView` up behind the `BottomView`.

I would like the `TableView` to come up and not be shown until it has passed the translucent `BottomView`. Should I initially set the `height` to zero and then change both the `y` and `height` on pan? Or should a mask the `tableView`? I'm trying to keep the `bottomView` translucent to see the image.

```
if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged){
    CGPoint translation = [gesture translationInView:self];
    direction = [self getDirection:translation];
    if (direction == kDirectionDown) {
        NSLog(@"DOWN");
    }else if (direction == kDirectionUp){
        CGRect frame = self.tableView.frame;
        CGPoint translation = [gesture locationInView:gesture.view];
        frame.origin.y = ([[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.height-50) + ((translation.y-initialP.y));
        if ([[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.height-frame.origin.y < self.tableView.frame.size.height+50) {
            [self.tableView setFrame:frame];
        }
 }
```

Comment: To clarify the view hierarchy:  I think you have a view controller with a main view that has three subviews, the first (bottom-most in z value) is an image view whose frame covers most/all of the parent.  The second is a table view whose frame initially lies below (y value) the parent.  The third (top most in z value) is a *translucent* (not transparent, because then we wouldn't see it) view that's framed to cover the bottom part (y value) of the parent.  Is that right?

Comment: @danh Yes thats correct. Changed above

Comment: Okay, and do you want to allow the user to drag the table?  Looks like you're trying to limit direction to up.  Is it possible you really want/need a UISwipeGestureRecognizer, looking for a swipe up?  That will simplify a lot of the frame calculation. Upon swipe, the tableview frame can have an animated trip from below it's parent view bound to the center of it's parent view.

Comment: @danh I also detect left <- -> right for other functionality. And the draggable tableView is something I would like to keep

Comment: What should happen if the user drags only part of the distance from hidden below to in the middle and then releases?

Comment: @danh I was going to implement a gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded and if the touch is past around half the distance, I'll finish the animation